# Clear codeigniter page cache on timed content change

Tags: codeigniter, caching

I have a Codeigniter site which has certain pages automatically changing at specific times, obviously when the change occurs I also need to delete the cache for the relevant page so visitors are not served the old version.

What is the best way to detect the need for a cache deletion? The new version of the page will only be created the first time someone visits it, so I need to detect when the amended page is visited for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

When you cache your output using the standard Codeigniter web page caching you are required to set the number of minutes the cache is valid for. After the time has expired CodeIgniter will not use the cache file, but will try to update it automatically.

If you really want to delete a cache file then you have to build the cache file name by using the md5 of the total uri, and remove the file from application/cache

Comment: Yes already got that bit covered, I basically need to know a neat way of triggering a cache delete (which I already have a function for) at a particular date and time. It could be done via CRON but I want to have a method entirely controllable within my Codeigniter CMS.